# How do you find the surface area of the boundary of a solid which lies in three cylinders?

Tags: area, surface, calculus

I would like to write down (but not evaluate) an iterated integral which gives the surface area of the boundary of the solid which lies in all three cylinders:

```
x^2 + z^2 = 9, 

y^2 + z^2 = 9, and 

x^2 + y^2 = 4
```

I am having trouble finding the boundaries of the iterated double integral. The surface area of the solid can be found using symmetry, since all cylinders are centred at (0,0,0).

[Visualization of the solid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0q07.png)
[Boundaries of the solid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw786.png)

Comment: I think you've asked this on the wrong site. Try [maths.se]